# angularJS modal, injected parameters

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Following `angular.ui` Modal [example](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) receives three parameters. while $scope is the injected variable, how are we getting the other two `$modal` and `$log`.  If they are injected automatically, how can one learn about all possible injected parameters?

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo')
    .controller('ModalDemoCtrl', 
        function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to get all services and controllers contained in a module, you can also use [_invokeQueue](http://taoofcode.net/studying-the-angular-injector-loading-modules/#_invokequeue), just do a `angular.module('yourModule')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(value){ console.log(value[2][0]) })`

Comment: Thanks for replying @evandro-silva, but this only returns the controllers defined by my module, while I was looking for a way to see all available services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Angular's documentation for its dependency injection is pretty good](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Essentially Angular will actually look at the function definition to do injection.  It's not that `$scope` is injected first, it's that `$scope` is injected because you are using the name `$scope` and that service exists.  Same with the other two.

You can inject any service available to the module.  [Services that ship with Angular itself (always available) are listed here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service), but you can define your own services and include other modules that define services too.

There are other methods of dependency injection that provide a bit more clarity:

```
("symbol", ["$scope", function (anotherName) {
```

In the above example, `anotherName` is actually the `$scope` service in the context of that function (although I recommend not changing service names).

Comment: Thanks @explosion-pills for the answer and the services list. I have a couple of follow up questions though. 1. $scope is not in the list ($rootscope is). Are they seen as same? 2. $modal is also not there, and it's not a service defined in the example.

Comment: 1. See [documentation on Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) 2. This is probably defined by a separate module.

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed injected automatically. [Over here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) you can find more information about how this actually works and see some of the parameters typically available for injection. Since you can make your own services, directives etc, I think it's unlikely you'll find an exhaustive list anywhere.

In fact, the $modal parameter for example isn't something magical in angular, but in fact a service that the angular ui team happened to write.

Comment: Thanks @Fasermaler, I am very new to angularJS and trying to find my way around. Really appreciate your time for answering this. I have been going through angularJS docs and other online tutorials. Most of the things are making sense now, but still it is work in progress.